# Is there any algorithm to find all the solutions of the following special linear Diophantine system?

Tags: diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations, integer-programming, network-flow, linear-diophantine-equations

Consider the following system.

1) $a_{11}x_1 + a_{21}x_2 + \cdots + a_{m1}x_m=d_1$

2) $a_{12}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + \cdots + a_{m2}x_m=d_2$

$\vdots$

n) $a_{1n}x_1 + a_{2n}x_2 + \cdots + a_{mn}x_m=d_n$

$\bullet$ $x_i\leq M_i$, for each $i=1, \cdots, m$.

For every $i=1, 2, \cdots, m $ and $j= 1, 2, \cdots, n$, we know that $a_{ij}$ is equal to $-1,\ 0$, or $1$.
All the right hand side amounts, $d_j$s, are zero exception of two of them which are nonzero and equal. Moreover, for each $i=1,\cdots, m$, $M_i$ is a given integer number.

I need an algorithm to solve and find all the integer solutions of the system. As I need to implement the algorithm, it would be nicer the algorithm being more practical and easy to implement.

Comment: Any chance you also want a lower bound on the $x_i$?

Comment: Do you have any relation between $m$ and $n$?

Comment: I have forgotten to say that I need to find the non negative solutions. So, we can consider $0$ as the lower bound for $x_i$s. Actually, $m$ is the number of arcs and $n$ is the number of nodes in a given connected network. So, we have $n-1 \leq m \leq n^2$.

Comment: Then the answer below still applies.  You will either discover no solutions to the linear system, one solution to the linear system (that may or may not be nonnegative, so may not satisfy your nonnegativity constraint), or an infinite family of solutions (for which detecting a nonnegative solution is straightforward because this is just some linear subspace).

Answer (score 3):

This is a linear system; as explained here, [systems of linear diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#System_of_linear_Diophantine_equations) can be solved by finding their [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) or [Hermite normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form).  (The first link explains how to use the Smith normal form in detail.  Using the Hermite normal form is analogous.  An online calculator for the Hermite method, using the "LLL-based algorithm of Havas-Majewski-Matthews" is [here](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/axb.html).)  [This question at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033067/solving-linear-diophantine-equation-systems-in-c) indicates that Octave and Octave embedded can do what you want.  [Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639260/algorithm-for-solving-systems-of-linear-diophantine-inequalities?rq=1) has an answer pointing to a python implementation of the Hermite/LLL/Havas-Majewski-Matthews solution, [Diophantine](https://github.com/tclose/Diophantine).

Comment: I tried to use Smith normal form of matrix $A$. Assume that $A=UBV$ such that $U$ and $V$ are non singular and $m\times m$  and $n\times n$ respectively. To solve the system $AX=d$, or equally $UBVX=d$, I need to compute first $d'=U^{-1}d$ which is easy. Then, assuming $Y=VX$, I can easily find the vector $Y$ solving the simple system $BY=d'$. Now, as I am implementing this process on MATLAB, I encounter the problem! Suppose that some of components in vector $Y$ are obtained as arbitrary variables. How I can find the vector $X$ using MATLAB program.

Comment: I don't have this entire problem reloaded from memory yet, but my first thought is if you get an infinite family of solutions, you're done as per the comment to the Question above.  You have a linear system (the $Y$ with variables) and you want to know if it has a solution in the first orthant.  This seems like a job for `linprog()`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Actually, I need to find all the solutions of the above mentioned system. I am using MATLAB. I need to make a code to do so. As you know, `linprog()` finds only the optimal solution according to objective function not all the ones. It is not enough to check if there is any solutions or not, I need to find all if there are any.